# Initializing argument 4 of void qsort() in C using structures

Tags: c, structure, void, qsort

I have a little problem there with error by using function qsort, it shows me:

> [Note] initializing argument 4 of 'void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t,
>   int (*)(const void*, const void*))'

it also shows the error:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int (*)(const student*, const
>   student*)' to 'int (*)(const void*, const void*)' [-fpermissive]

```
int n;
            qsort ((void*) databaza, size, sizeof(struct student), compare);
            for (n=0; n<size; n++)
            {  
            printf ("%d %s",databaza[SIZE].votes,databaza[SIZE].name);  
            }
            return 0;
```

where the compare function looks like

```
int compare(const struct student* p1, const struct student* p2){
           return ( p1->votes - p2->votes );
}
```

in structure

```
struct student {
    char name[SIZE];
    int votes;
};


int find_student(struct student* students,int size, const char* name){
   for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
    int results=strcmp(students[i].name,name);
      if(results==0){
          return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening, I am quite new in structures and functions like qsort.

Comment: " why is this happening," --> The compare function's signature should be `const void*, const void*`, not `const struct student* p1, const struct student* p2`.

Comment: const void is not a pointer to object type

Comment: @Chris: `const void *` is a pointer to object type, and you do not have a choice about the type of the `qsort` argument. It must be `int (*)(const void *, const void *)`.